# How to upload and download file from a server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, download

I am developing a webpage in that the user can download their Resume for Edit. So I have a link to download the article. I use the following code for download.

```
DataTable dt = user.getUserDetails(2);
user.WriteFileFromDBbyUserArticleID(Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0])), Convert.ToInt32(2), "CV");
FileUtil.writeFileToResponse(Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0])), Response);

////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void WriteFileFromDBbyUserArticleID(string FilePath, int UserID, string FileType)
{
    DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();

    string selectQuery = "Select Articles.Users_WriteFileFromDB(?,?,? ) from Articles.Users";

    DbParameter[] parm = new DbParameter[3];
    parm[0] = dal.GetParameter();
    parm[0].ParameterName = "@FilePath";
    parm[0].Value = FilePath;

    parm[1] = dal.GetParameter();
    parm[1].ParameterName = "@UserID";
    parm[1].Value = UserID;

    parm[2] = dal.GetParameter();
    parm[2].ParameterName = "@FileType";
    parm[2].Value = FileType;

    DataTable dtArticleStatus = dal.ExecuteDataTable(selectQuery, parm);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static public void writeFileToResponse(string filePath,HttpResponse Response)
{
    try
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.Flush();
        File.Delete(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I got the error in the line "Response.WriteFile(filePath);" as follows

> sys.webforms.pagerequestManagerparserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to response.write(), response filters, httpModules, or server trace is enabled.
>   Details:Error parsing near ...

How do I fix this?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: There should be reputation score which allowed you to vote users for close, I would vote Sakthivel.

Comment: For close ? What can i do to avoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request["file"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string file = context.Server.MapPath("~/files/" + context.Request["file"].ToString());
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    context.Response.ClearContent();
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fi.Name);
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
                    string fExtn = "video/avi";
                    context.Response.ContentType = fExtn;
                    context.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
                    context.Response.End();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stream the document back using Response stream.

This might get you going.

[Response](http://forums.asp.net/t/1159236.aspx)

[Request, Response Objects](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/forms/response.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET? Try HtmlInputFile for the uploads.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I was going mostly by the title since the question was a bit confusing, but reading it again it seems you might be right. Either way, leaving this answer here will help oher users that find this question from the title.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file you can use `asp:FileUpload` control and simple use `SaveAs` method. But be aware that if you use it in combination with partial update object (`asp:UpdatePanel`) that you'll allso have to set triggers. If you don't use triggers `asp:FileUpload` control can be resetted...